# Application development (behind the scenes)

Tags: java, javascript, android, mysql, performance

My name is Kevin and I'm new to this so I'll keep everything short and sweet.

I've learned the basics of android app development but I was wondering how I was able to monetise my application? Meaning, I can get regular statistics on how well my application is doing. I don't know if Google offers that but I haven't been able to find anything. I was wondering if anyone had any knowledge of the back-end coding in an android app and if it is possible to connect your own independent server to control all the requests and data-transfers?

Sorry guys if to the experts this sounds like a naive question, but I am only 16, not has that much experience or exposure.

Comment: I would recommend that you read [the site documentation on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This is a site for programming questions, not questions regarding monetization or analytics analysis. The part of your question that is on-topic ("is possible to connect your own independent server to control all the requests and data-transfer") is confusing. You may wish to either edit this question or ask a fresh question where you explain, in much more detail, what you are trying to do and what your concerns are.

Comment: Was *networking* a part of your "basics of android app development"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Hello there everyone, I'm sorry Just seen your comments about my question I only made this account like an hour ago and had no experience on this before. I will improve the phrasing of my question in the future and on a light note thank you for fast replies and your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello **Kevin Kimani**,

There is a method to control your app, and Google already offers it.

It's called **Google Mobile App Analytics**.
You can check more about that @ https://www.google.pt/analytics/mobile/

For the second Part of your question, yes it is possible to do that, you just need to make a **REST** request from your application to your server, and from that Manage your App's statistics.

I know a company that offers this service for developers, they even program your RESTful api and the backoffice if you want. I think their website is in maintenance atm, but you can check it @ http://qiteam.org. You'll find a contact form for that.

Best Regards.